# Get all values of key in JSON string

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON stringified variable containing some dates with the following format:

```
var labs = {
    "2016-01-07":[{
        "date":"2016-01-07T12:45:00.000Z",
        "duration":120,
        "location":"ExampleLocation"
    }],
    "2017-01-05":[{
        "date": "2017-01-05T14:45:00.000Z",
        "duration": 120,
        "location": "ExampleLocation"
      },{
        "date": "2017-01-05T14:45:00.000Z",
        "duration": 120,
        "location": "ExampleLocation"
     }];
}
```

Now I want those dates to be written in an angular material calendar. It is done with this code:

```
$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
        var key = [date.getFullYear(), numFmt(date.getMonth()+1),    numFmt(date.getDate())].join("-");
        var data = (labs[key] || [{ date: ""}])[0].date.slice(11, 16);
        $scope.dayContent = data; //Returns the time and prints it into the calendar cell
```

This only works for the first object of each day, so the second date at "2017-01-05" isnt't printed out. How can I access all values and print each of the dates in the respective calendar cell?
I already logged `(labs[key] || [{ date: ""}])[1]` but it was undefined.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You have an array after the value of `"2017-01-05"` without a key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start, your `labs` variable is invalid. It should actually be:

```
var labs = {
    "2016-01-07":[{
        "date":"2016-01-07T12:45:00.000Z",
        "duration":120,
        "location":"ExampleLocation"
    }],
    "2017-01-05":[{
        "date": "2017-01-05T14:45:00.000Z",
        "duration": 120,
        "location": "ExampleLocation"
      }, {
        "date": "2017-01-05T14:45:00.000Z",
        "duration": 120,
        "location": "ExampleLocation"
     }]
};
```

Next, I am unsure from the code if you are trying to assign the lab's entry value for the given date, or if you are trying to assign the entire matching lab entry. If you just want just the data, try:

```
$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
    var key = [date.getFullYear(), numFmt(date.getMonth()+1), numFmt(date.getDate()+1)].join("-");
    var data = labs[key] || [];
    $scope.dayContent = data; //Returns the time and prints it into the calendar cell
};
```

If you are wanting to assign the entire entry:

```
$scope.setDayContent = function(date) {
    var key = [date.getFullYear(), numFmt(date.getMonth()+1), numFmt(date.getDate()+1)].join("-");
    var data = {};
    data[date] = labs[key] || [];
    $scope.dayContent = data; //Returns the time and prints it into the calendar cell
};
```

Also, I am assuming that the `numFmt` has the following functionality:

```
var numFmt = function(num) {
  if (num < 10) return '0' + num;
  return num.toString();
};
```

I hope this helps :)